# An unusual shopping list

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

6 bears
3 cucumbers
2 winks
2 birds
5 sheets
3 judges
2 bones
2 dogs
3 houses
4 feathers
1 rake
3 posts
4 daisies
3 razors
1 bat
3 lords
4 pancakes
2 boards
3 peacocks
5 whistles

Comment: Looks like a perfectly normal shopping list to me ...

Comment: @msh210 You only bought whistles? What about the bells?

Comment: @Avi, hey, at least I have as many bones as I do dogs.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, I thank you for the compliment:

> **YOU'RE BRIGHT AS A BUTTON**

The list comprises:

> Objects/creatures/people that appear in common 'as adjective as a noun' idioms:
>
>   As *hungr**Y*** as a bear
>  As *co**O**l* as a cucumber
>  As *q**U**ick* as a wink
>  As *f**R**ee* as a bird
>  As *whit**E*** as a sheet
>  As *so**B**er* as a judge
>  As *d**R**y* as a bone
>  As *s**I**ck* as a dog
>  As *bi**G*** as a house
>  As *lig**H**t* as a feather
>  As ***T***hin as a rake
>  As *de**A**f* as a post
>  As *fre**S**h* as a daisy
>  As *sh**A**rp* as a razor
>  As ***B***lind as a bat
>  As *dr**U**nk* as a lord
>  As *fla**T*** as a pancake
>  As *s**T**iff* as a board
>  As *pr**O**ud* as a peacock
>  As *clea**N*** as a whistle

Next:

> Reading the letter in the newly discovered adjective that occupies the position indicated by the corresponding number in the shopping list, we find the hidden message: **YOU'RE BRIGHT AS A BUTTON!**